# Adding a PHP file to display in HTML file

Tags: php, html, database

I have a file in PHP that is calling for all the line items in a database and it displays a table with all the line items. I have an HTML page that has a form to add items to a database for a restaurant menu. I want the PHP file used to display all the line items to be called in this html page so it will display the table on the page in addition to the form I have. How do I do this?

Here's my code for the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin_index.css"/>
            <title>B Place</title>
        </head>

        <body id = "bodyStyler">
            <h1 id ="header">
                <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo"/>
            </h1>
            <table id = "pageLinks">
                <tr>
                    <td class="buttons"><b><a href="admin_index.html">Home</a></b></td>
                    <td class="buttons"><b><a href="admin_menu.html">Menu</a></b></td>
                    <td class="buttons"><b><a href="admin_volleyball.html">Volleyball</a></b></td>
                    <td id="endButton"><b><a href="admin_blog.html">Blog</a></b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="content">
                <h1 id="bodyText"> Menu </h1>
                <table>
                    <form method="post" action="input_menu.php">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="chart">Product Name:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="productName" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="chart">Product Type:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="type" value=""  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="chart">Product Price:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="price" value=""  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="chart">Product is a Special:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="isSpecial" value=""  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="chart">Day of the Week Product is a Special:</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="specialDay" value=""  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php include 'admin_menu_lineitems.php';?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my code of the PHP file(admin_menu_lineitems.php) I want to include:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("b_place", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th> Type </th>
<th> Product Name </th>
<th> Price </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['productName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're including it already, at the bottom of the page. Does that not work?

Comment: I can't see a closing </form> tag

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (and by far most common) approach is to:

- Rename your HTML page to be a PHP page
- Cut and paste your PHP code into the appropriate part of the final page

That way, the whole page will be processed as PHP.

Any links pointing to this page would have to point to the renamed page instead.

If you do not rename the .html file to be a .php file, the PHP processor will not act on the page (by default, anyhow) and will just output the PHP code directly to the browser without running it.

Comment: This assumes your server selects processors by file extension... which it probably does (e.g. Apache), but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use require or include to achieve your aim:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

or ... (if you must)

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: Well... the .html file needs to be processed by PHP for this to work.

Comment: He didn't state what file format his HTML document was in, and I was assuming he was using a .php extension because of the other file. However, you are indeed correct as I should not assume! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make your server run html as php file, if you dont want to rename. check this post: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the general responses so far, the HTML code should be within a file with a file extension of .php not .html in order for ANY of the PHP to work. I have made some small changes to the html below (remember to use your end tags), however the PHP seems to be OK so the include should work fine.

```
<?php
  /** (the include file) **/
  $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
  mysql_select_db("database", $db);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>".
          "<td>". $row["type"] . "</td>".
          "<td>". $row["productName"] . "</td>".
          "<td>". $row["price"] . "</td>".
         "</tr>";
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin_index.css"/>
  <title>B Place</title>
</head>

<body id="bodyStyler">
  <h1 id="header"><img src="logo.jpg" id="logo"/></h1>
  <table id="pageLinks">
    <tr>
      <td class="buttons"><b><a href="admin_index.html">Home</a></b></td>
      <td class="buttons"><b><a href="admin_menu.html">Menu</a></b></td>
      <td class="buttons"><b><a href="admin_volleyball.html">Volleyball</a></b></td>
      <td id="endButton"><b><a href="admin_blog.html">Blog</a></b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="content">
    <h1 id="bodyText"> Menu </h1>

    <form method="post" action="input_menu.php">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="chart">Product Name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="productName" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="chart">Product Type:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="type" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="chart">Product Price:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="price" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="chart">Product is a Special:</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="isSpecial" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="chart">Day of the Week Product is a Special:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="specialDay" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <?php include 'admin_menu_lineitems.php';?>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's old school but why not use an iframe?
But it is much cleaner to rename the page .php and use a web server to view the page.
If you dont have one yet, wamp / xamp is easy enough.